# Reference for understanding vortex physics in superconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, vortex

I have been trying to find a good reference to understand the motion of vortices in type-II superconductors. While most textbooks on superconductivity talk qualitatively about this subject, I have been looking for advanced material, that actually discuss the intricacies of arriving at equations of motion for Abrikosov's vortices.

Answer (score 1):

Suprisingly this is still a controversial topic. There are a number of different approaches that give different answers to the motion. A logically based theory is here

Alan T. Dorsey *Vortex motion and the Hall effect in type-II superconductors: A time-dependent Ginzburg-Landau theory approach*,
Phys. Rev. B 46, 8376 (1992)

but this does model not agree with experiment in all cases.

A more recent paper with lots of references is

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.10062.pdf

but the logic as what causes the phase of the order parameter to evolve  is not clear to me.

Comment: From what I understand the Ginsburg Landau models are valid only close to $T_{c}$ as the expansion of free energy in terms of order parameter would be limited at most quadratic terms in that case. I am curious to know if there are more general approaches to this problem at much lower temperatures and fields slightly above $H_{c1}$. I wonder specifically about this regime as I assume this would be case where vortices are well separated and also stable. I believe it is called the vortex solid phase.

Comment: You can use generalized L-G models that are valid away from $T_c$. They have the right symmetries and degrees of freedom etc.

Comment: I found a slightly older review by Cyrot, 
https://doi.org/10.1088/0034-4885/36/2/001 
But, I couldn't find a review that seems to discuss generalised Ginzburg-Landau models.